# PhpExcel getting mixed data

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am trying to import excel .xls document with phpexcel and insert it into table with mysql.

Problem is that getCell is getting mixed data from cell and row.

Here is my code.

```
            if($_FILES['excel']['name'])
        {
            Db::query('TRUNCATE TABLE povijesni_podaci');

            $files = glob('upload_data/excel/'); // get all file names
            foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
              if(is_file($file))
                unlink($file); // delete file
            }

            include(_SITE_ROOT.'lib/phpexcel/PHPExcel.php');
            include(_SITE_ROOT.'lib/phpexcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
            include(_SITE_ROOT.'lib/phpexcel/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php');

            $file_name = clean_uri($_FILES['excel']['name']);
            $file_name = 'povijest_'.$file_name;
            $folder_s = 'upload_data/excel';

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'], '../'.$folder_s.'/'.$file_name);

            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('../'.$folder_s.'/'.$file_name);
            $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true); 
            $highestColumm = 'K';
            $colNumber = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumm);
            $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet); 

            //var_dump($allDataInSheet); exit;

                for($i=7;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
                    $datum = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue();
                    $skip = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getValue();
                    $prva = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$i)->getValue();
                    $zadnja = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D'.$i)->getValue();
                    $najvisa = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E'.$i)->getValue();
                    $najniza = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('F'.$i)->getValue();
                    $prosjecna = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('G'.$i)->getValue();
                    $promjena = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('H'.$i)->getValue();
                    $broj_transakcija = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I'.$i)->getValue();
                    $kolicina = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('J'.$i)->getValue();
                    $promet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('K'.$i)->getValue();                      

                    //var_dump($broj_transakcija);exit;

                    Db::query('INSERT INTO povijesni_podaci SET datum = "'.$datum.'",
                                                                vrsta_prometa = "'.$skip.'",
                                                                prva = "'.$prva.'",
                                                                zadnja= "'.$zadnja.'",
                                                                najvisa = "'.$najvisa.'",
                                                                najniza = "'.$najniza.'",
                                                                prosjecna = "'.$prosjecna.'",
                                                                promjena = "'.$promjena.'",
                                                                broj_transakcija = "'.$broj_transakcija.'",
                                                                kolicina = "'.$kolicina.'",
                                                                promet = "'.$promet.'",
                                                                created = NOW() ');

                    var_dump('INSERT INTO povijesni_podaci SET datum = "'.$datum.'",
                                                                vrsta_prometa = "'.$skip.'",
                                                                prva = "'.$prva.'",
                                                                zadnja= "'.$zadnja.'",
                                                                najvisa = "'.$najvisa.'",
                                                                najniza = "'.$najniza.'",
                                                                prosjecna = "'.$prosjecna.'",
                                                                promjena = "'.$promjena.'",
                                                                broj_transakcija = "'.$broj_transakcija.'",
                                                                kolicina = "'.$kolicina.'",
                                                                promet = "'.$promet.'",
                                                                created = NOW() ');
                    exit;
                }           


        }
```

and here is my var_dump:

```
string(594) "INSERT INTO povijesni_podaci SET datum = " 20.01.2016N72", vrsta_prometa = "9970", prva = "0072", zadnja= "9970", najvisa = "0070", najniza = "29- 4", prosjecna = "102", promjena = "00115", broj_transakcija = "008.082", kolicina = "89", promet = "", created = NOW() "
```

He is getting every one and half cell ??

date       | prva  | zadnja
20.01.2016   72,99   70

Comment: So what format is your uploaded file? Is it really a BIFF or OfficeOpenXML file? Or is it a CSV file? If the latter, what is the separator?